# 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I get this error:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details
>
> SqlException: Procedure or function SP_WEB_MS3DailyReport_DailyEquipmentDeviation_SelectByDate has too many arguments specified.

My code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_WEB_MS3DailyReport_NonBuilDeviation_SelectByDate]
    (@FromDate datetime,
     @EndDate datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        JobHead,
        ISNULL(MeasurementPlanned, 0) AS MeasurementPlanned,
        CASE
           WHEN Deviation IS NULL THEN CONVERT(Numeric(18, 2), 0)
           ELSE CONVERT(Numeric(18, 2), MeasurementReport)
        END AS MeasurementReport,
        CASE
           WHEN MeasurementReport IS NULL THEN -(MeasurementPlanned)
           ELSE Deviation
        END AS Deviation,
        CASE
           WHEN MeasurementPlanned IS NULL AND Deviation > 0 THEN 'btn-info'
           WHEN Deviation = 0 THEN 'btn-primary'
           WHEN Deviation > 0 THEN 'btn-success'
           WHEN Deviation < 0 THEN 'btn-danger' 
           WHEN Deviation IS NULL THEN 'btn-warning'
        END AS Indicater,
        ProjectSiteName, ProjectSiteID
    FROM
        (SELECT
             DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation.[JobHead],
             CONVERT(Numeric(18, 2), NextDayNonBuildPlan.Measurement) AS MeasurementPlanned,
             CONVERT(Numeric(18, 2), DailyNonBuildReport.Measurement) AS MeasurementReport,
             CONVERT(Numeric(18, 2), DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation.Measurement) AS Deviation,
             ProjectSiteName, DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation.ProjectSiteID
         FROM
             DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation
         LEFT JOIN
             NextDayNonBuildPlan ON DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation.NextDayNonBuildPlanID = NextDayNonBuildPlan.NextDayNonBuildPlanID
         LEFT JOIN 
             [DailyNonBuildReport] ON DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation.DailyNonBuildReportID = DailyNonBuildReport.DailyNonBuildReportID
         INNER JOIN 
             ProjectSites ON ProjectSites.ProjectSiteID = DailyNonBuildReviewDeviation.ProjectSiteID
         WHERE 
             [DayOFDeviation] BETWEEN CONVERT(date, @FromDate) AND CONVERT(date, @EndDate))AA
    GROUP BY 
        ProjectSiteName, ProjectSiteID, JobHead, 
        MeasurementPlanned, MeasurementReport, Deviation
END
```

Comment: Posting the code to a different stored procedure is NOT helpful. But the problem here is in your application code - which you did not post.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: How is this related to C# and Entity Framework?

Comment: **this storedprocedure calling from this code**                                                             ` public List<SP_WEB_MS3DailyReport_NonBuilDeviation_SelectByDate_Result> 
  NonBuilDeviation_SelectByDate(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndtDate)
      {
          return Obj.SP_WEB_MS3DailyReport_NonBuilDeviation_SelectByDate(StartDate, EndtDate).ToList();
      }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments. Also, make sure that the code doesn't contain black boxes (like `Obj.SP_WEB_MS3DailyReport_NonBuilDeviation_SelectByDate`).

Answer (score 0):

"has too many arguments specified.". You are calling a stored procedure from your application code that has to many parameters than what's defined in your store procedure. Make sure the parameters match up. Please post your application code if you need additional help.